# Uploading photos to instagram, using a script

Tags: php, instagram, photos

Is it possible to upload photos from a webpage to Instagram, if so how do you do it?

I am wondering how to do this, so I can have a website where people can vote on their favourite photo and the one with most votes will be posted each day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading on Instagram is possible.

```
POST https://instagram.com/api/v1/media/upload/
```

Check this code for example https://code.google.com/p/twitubas/source/browse/common/instagram.php

My challenge is out for people to fix this script so it is stand alone!

Comment: Uhm, are you posting this Q/A pair to promote your script?

Comment: Not my script, I spent about an hour looking for a script along this lines and finally found it @damienPirsy

Comment: People aren't going to write your code for you, please don't mask it as a "challenge". You have three options; either learn how to write it yourself, pay someone to do it or find another solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this API: https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API

And here is an example how to upload photo to Instagram:

```
<?php
require '../src/Instagram.php';
/////// CONFIG ///////
$username = '';
$password = '';
$debug    = false;
$photo    = '';     // path to the photo
$caption  = null;   // caption
//////////////////////
$i = new Instagram($username, $password, $debug);
try{
  $i->login();
} catch (InstagramException $e)
{
  $e->getMessage();
  exit();
}
try {
  $i->uploadPhoto($photo, $caption);
} catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This needs composer installed and can't be used in a shared hosting?

Comment: API no more avaliable